# Nodejs&passport data duplicates when creating

Tags: node.js

```js
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    User.register(new User({username: req.body.username, email: req.body.email}), req.body.password, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
          res.redirect("keywordList");
        });
    });
});
```

Signing up works good but when I sign up it creates the same data twice. If I were to sign up with JohnDoe username, email  and password it would create 2 same data.

Example: [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think `User.register` method that you impelemented already creates a user for you and `new User({"email":req.body.email,"username":req.body.username});` creates a user object and also creates a user in the DB.

Comment: Even when I do User.create({email: req.body.email...}) gets duplicated